# C# Trouble saving the input in a datagridview to the database

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, save, entity

I am having trouble coding a Save button for a datagridview, and I am not to sure what is going wrong. If I make the edits, click the save button; the data stays modified until I close the application and reload it. At that point the data is no longer modified. I am using an Entity Framework rather than sqlconnection so the examples I have viewed regarding this have not been too helpful. Below is the code for my Save button as present. It's based of a code generated automatically by the customersNavigation_SaveClick event, which is not needed as the navigation bar was removed.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.incidentsBindingSource1.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.techSupportDataSet);
    }
```

Comment: So the problem is that while the updates exist in memory they aren't being persisted to the database?  Well, where do you persist the changes to the database?

Comment: If you are binding to a DataTable you need to use the AcceptChanges() method to update table after changes.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I looked into what you mentioned about AcceptChanges(). and noted that I should have been using a SaveChanges(), While AcceptChanges its not method that I used, it didn give me a better idea of what I need to do. It was with an Entity which uses SaveChanges rather than AcceptChanges in this particular scenario, Appreciate your assistance.